# Using NPM, Gulp, Grunt, Bower etc with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, package-managers

I've been trying for the past couple of weeks to get my head around the use of the new front end tool chain for web development. In particular using NPM, Bower and primarily Gulp but initially Grunt, to manage front end packages and integrate with my Visual Studio 2013 IDE.

What I can't seem to get my head around is the Gulp/Grunt aspect of this tool chain. I appreciate the NPM and BOWER are just package managers similar to NuGet and simply download code/files to reference.

However, and I'm seriously hoping I'm missing something simple, is how the hell do I get these packages to put the correct file types in the correct locations. e.g. all js files in my Scripts folder, all less/sass files compiled to my "Content" folder? In turn how can I get this to happen when I install a package so when I create my reference in my html files to relevant libraries I'm referring to a "Bower_components" folder or similar?

I've read over various tutorials, the most recent of which seemed to get me quite a long way there but then I got lost at the end ([The tutorial](http://idisposable.co.uk/2015/02/switching-the-client-side-build-library-in-visual-studio-2013-mvc-template-to-gulp-and-bower/)). Which has is what has lead me to the conclusion it is the gulp element of things I'm not getting.

Is it possible to get the files to auto include when added to the project or generated by the Gulp task?

Comment: From what I've seen, you don't. The integration simply isn't there yet in 2013.

Comment: I use [Task Runner Explorer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx). I use it with Grunt, but as far as I know Gulp should work with it similarly